# OnClickListener для RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

**Мой код:**

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView txtViewTitle;
    private ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.album_icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext, SecondActivity.class;
```

**Тут ошибка-->**  startActivity(intent) 
        }
    }

то есть, как будто этого метода не существует!

**Вопрос:**

1) Что неправильно написал?

2) Как добавлить клик, если item-ы RecylerView будет динамически увеличиваться?

Comment: скобки после `SecondActivity.class` нет. Какая ошибка? мы же не экстрасенсы. Мне кажется статическим класс  ViewHolder делать не верно

Comment: @miha_dev да, по-моему там дело просто в скобке, хотя IDE должен все подсвечивать.

Comment: Нет это просто опечатка!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Передавайте context в конструктор. Вот так по идее правильно:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(сontext, SecondActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

В activity/fragment-e добавьте данный слушатель:

```
 yourRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                           //click
                        }
                    })
            );
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!!!!

Comment: @Omuradil да незачто)

Comment: на второй вопрос это сгодится?

Comment: Вам надо делать клик по конкретный элементам в итиме списка? или же клик по целому итему?

Comment: По итемам только

Comment: обновил ответ, проверь

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, включили мою логику!